# Conditional windowing function sql

Tags: sql, hive

I am looking to query a set of data by date, but only if a condition over the last 7 days is true.

Something like,

```
SELECT 
category_name,
entity_id
FROM table_name
WHERE 
condition_1 = True 
AND date_id <= current_date AND date_id >= current_date - 7
```

But I would want to query over a window of multiple date ids at the same time.

Let's say I have

```
2016-01-01, foo, 123, True
2015-12-31, foo, 123, False
2015-12-26, foo, 123, True
2015-12-31, bar, 12345, False
```

And have a standard table of dates which I'll join on such as

```
2015-01-01,
2015-01-02,
...
```

since my first table wont necessarily have a record for each day

I would expect the result to be

```
2016-01-01, foo, 123, True
2016-12-31, foo ,123, True
2016-12-30, foo ,123, True
2016-12-29, foo ,123, True
2016-12-28, foo ,123, True
2016-12-27, foo ,123, True
2016-12-26, foo ,123, True
```

Since those are the dates where condition 1 is true over the past 7 days. What's the best way to do this? I have tried something like

```
        SUM(condition_1) OVER (ORDER BY date_id
            ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

along with joining on a date table (to ensure i always have a dateid populated). But, I am not sure if this is the best implementation and I am not getting the correct results (still debugging).

Comment: I don't get your example.  Your are starting with 4 rows and then getting 7?

Comment: Yeah I would need to join on a date table (ill try to edit my post to be a bit clearer) since my initial table won't necessarily have a record for each date.

Comment: Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want a `left join` for your query:

```
SELECT t.category_name, t.entity_id,
       SUM(condition_1) OVER (ORDER BY c.date_id
                              ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             )
FROM calender c LEFT JOIN
     table_name t
     ON c.date_id = t.date_id AND t. condition_1 = True ;
```

I don't think `SUM(condition_1)` returns true or false -- perhaps `MAX()` or an aggregation boolean `OR`.  However, that is what you put in the question.

Comment: If only I could use these in MySQL @Gordon Linoff!

Comment: @MontyPython . . . You can always switch to Postgres or another database that does support them.

Comment: You are right but MySQL works just fine for me. I work my way around, somehow.